How to get rid of metadata warnings in VS Code?
I installed the VS Code Flutter intl extension and use it to translate a Flutter app. After setting up the extension, my "Problems" pane in VS Code is full of warnings, one for each key and translation file. Since I don't plan to add metadata for every key, this is quite annoying. Does anyone know of a way to disable the warnings?


Add this to settings.json
"arb-editor.suppressedWarnings": [
  "missing_metadata_for_key"
],

For details config, see: https://github.com/google/arb-editor

Turns out that these warnings are coming from the ARB Editor extension and there is an open PR to solve this issue: https://github.com/google/arb-editor/issues/48
